# Why might my "setError and setLoading" be giving an undefined? (React project)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm adding authentication to a react app with a basic signup page, I have an async/await function to handle the submit and have the setError and setLoading declared with the useState hook, however I get an error saying:

Failed to compile
src/pages/Signup.js
Line 17:14:  'setError' is not defined    no-undef
Line 20:7:   'setError' is not defined    no-undef
Line 21:7:   'setLoading' is not defined  no-undef
Line 24:7:   'setError' is not defined    no-undef
Line 27:5:   'setLoading' is not defined  no-undef

here is my code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";

export default function Signup() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
  const { signup } = useAuth();
  const [error, serError] = useState("");
  const [loading, serLoading] = useState(false);

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords do not match");
    }
    try {
      setError("");
      setLoading(true);
      await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to create account");
    }

    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        Already have an account? Log in
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I know it's easy to overlook something simple, can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state is misspelled. `const [error, serError] = useState("");` should be `const [error, setError] = useState("");` and the same for `setLoading`, you have `serLoading`.

Comment: Man... thats what I meant when I said Its easy to overlook something simple. lol Thanks alot Rolando.

Comment: You welcome, it happens to all of us. And mark my answer as correct!